# GridSearchCV and LogisticRegression raise ValueError: Can't handle mix of continuous and binary

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run gridsearch with LogisticRegression, and get

```
ValueError: Can't handle mix of continuous and binary
```

I've traced this error to `metrics.accuracy_score`. Apparently the prediction doesn't go so well, and while the y_true is continuous (as is the rest of the data), y_pred is all zeros and is thus classified as binary.

- Is there any way to avoid this error?
- Does the nature of y_pred means I have no business using logistic regression at all, or could this be a result of the parameters used?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly logistic regression is actually a classification algorithm (see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression). As such the target ("y_true") data that you feed it should be binary. If you are actually trying to solve a regression problem you should choose a different algorithm, e.g. LinearRegression, SVR, RandomForestRegressor, etc.

Comment: LogisticRegression can be used if there are fixed number of labels

Comment: Despite the above comment, this is of course the right answer. Feeling stupid, thanks.

Comment: @AbishekThakur, yeah that's a good point, but note that for multi-class LR scikit-learn uses a one-vs-all wrapper around the binary LR algorithm.

Comment: Still in terms of API, the `LogisticRegression` objects wants class labels, not necessarily [0,1] vectors.